# How to deal with "Warning: object 'xxx' is created by more than one data call"

Tags: r, package, warnings

When checking an R package, I got the warning

```
Warning: object 'xxx' is created by more than one data call
```

What causes this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 14):

This warning occurs when multiple `RData` files in the `data` directory of the package store a variable with the same name.

To reproduce, we create a package and save the `cars` dataset twice, to different files:

```
library(devtools)    
create("test")   
dir.create("test/data")    
save(cars, file = "test/data/cars1.RData")
save(cars, file = "test/data/cars2.RData")   
check("test")
```

The output from `check` includes these lines:

> Found the following significant warnings:
>     Warning: object 'cars' is created by more than one data call

---

If you receive this warning, you can find repeated variable names using:

```
rdata_files <- dir("test/data", full.names = TRUE, pattern = "\\.RData$")
var_names <- lapply(
  rdata_files,
  function(rdata_file)
  {
    e <- new.env()
    load(rdata_file, envir = e)
    ls(e)
  }
)

Reduce(intersect, var_names)
## [1] "cars"
```

Comment: Does this mean it's not possible to have multiple RData files with the same variable names?   Is the solution to store all in one RData file (e.g. several dataframes as a list?)

Comment: @jalapic: You can either have one variable containing a list of data frames, or separate variables with different names.  In the above example, you could call them `cars1`, `cars2`, etc. Which you choose depends upon what's easiest for the your users.